# Creating an array of dictionaries plist

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, plist

I am creating a plist of dictionaries. The plist starts off as empty, and then I do this:

```
NSMutableArray *favouritesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
[favouritesList addObject:thisPlace]; // where thisPlace is some NSDictionary
[favouritesList writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

When I immediately do:

```
NSArray *savedFav = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSLog(@"%@", savedFav);
```

I get an empty array. Why is this? Why isn't it writing properly? I am setting up the plist correctly, I debugged that. But I cannot add a dictionary to it.

The plist is just an empty plist with a root that's an array

**EDIT:**

Here is how I construct my path:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"favourites.plist"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
    NSString *sourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"favourites" ofType:@"plist"];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:path error:nil];
}
```

Comment: Have you logged `path` to make sure it's valid? Does it point to a file in the `Documents` directory? How did you construct `path`? Did you check to see if `writeToFile` returned `TRUE`?

Comment: Yes, see the edit for how I made my path

Comment: If the plist file is empty, then the first initialization fails and returns `nil`. You have to check that and allocate-initialize a valid but empty array.

Comment: You just need to go through, line by line, and check the success of every step. You don't appear to be checking whether any of these lines succeeded or failed, so it's hard for us to diagnose where you're going wrong.

Comment: Is thisPlace a dictionary with only "plistables" (aka: strings, dates, arrays, numbers and dicts) values?

Comment: @H2CO3 I think this may be the issue. Which initialisation though (which line)? I already heck if fileManager file does not exist. Does this go in there?

Comment: @Darksky Nope. The initialization of the array.

Comment: @H2CO3 My `favouritesList` returns an empty NSArray. But adding a dictionary to it works. I'm not sure how this is failing.

Comment: My `writeToFile` is returning `NO`, but all my dictionary values are strings or numbers.

Comment: @Darksky Log out the path. Maybe it's invalid/bogus.

Comment: Actually I got it. I have an NSNull in the dictionary. I'm assuming I will need to change that to say the string "null". The debugger shows NSNull as a string and so I thought it was a string.

Comment: Change to use JSON rather than plist.  JSON is perfectly happy with an NSNull.

Comment: @HotLicks I need to store it in a plist. What are you talking about?

Comment: @Darksky - If you need it to be in a plist file, so be it.  If you just need to store it in a file, JSON is a perfectly valid alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I do something like below.  I add an object using a key.  Maybe that's why it's not working.

static NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryStore;

```
+(void)initialize{
    if(dictionaryStore == nil){
        dictionaryStore = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self getFilePath]];
        if(dictionaryStore == nil)
            dictionaryStore = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    }
}

+(NSString *)getFilePath{
    NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename.plist"];
    return plistPath;
}

+(NSString *)getValueForKey:(NSString *)key{
    [self initialize];

    return [dictionaryStore objectForKey:key];
}

+(void)setValue:(NSString *)value forKey:(NSString *)key{
    [self initialize];

    [dictionaryStore setValue:value forKey:key];
}

+(BOOL)save{
    [self initialize];

    return [dictionaryStore writeToFile:[self getFilePath] atomically:YES];
}
```

Edit:
So to save a value, I do:

```
[WAStore setValue:myValue forKey:myKey];
BOOL isSuccessful = [WAStore save];
```

WAStore is the class name.  myValue can be most data types (NSManagedObjectModels won't work).  myKey is any NSString.